# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

Hola llevo intentando un par de dias mirando respuesta a preguntas similares en esta web pero nada de las soluciones que veo parece funcionar o al leerlas no concluyo en una explicacion clara, mi caso es el siguiente:

Hago una peticion por postman a una api que se llama GeoVictoria, me devuelve los datos perfectamente pero a la hora de pasarla por ajax la peticion a esa api me tira ese error.

Entonces no entiendo si le tengo que pasar yo el header, cosa que ya he hecho y no funciona con header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); , o es que lo tienen que habilitar ellos desde la api para que desde mi dominio se pueda acceder.

```
    <?php
    include("libs/php/conexion_intranet.php");
    include("libs/php/funciones_intranet.php");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "https://customerapi-sandbox.geovictoria.com/api/v1/Login",
                data: {
                    "User":"******",
                    "Password":"******"
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Respuesta corta: Si son ellos, es la api la que tiene que agregar la cabecera.
Este es el error más nefasto de hoy en día el error de CORS. Este mecanismo de "seguridad" lo implementa el navegador por ese motivo funciona desde Postman pero no desde tu javascript. La única alternativa que a mí me ha resultado, es crear una API intermedia en mi servidor (a modo de proxy), entonces yo consulto a mi api, y mi api desde el servidor consulta la otra api.

Comment: Otra posibilidad sería traer los datos mediante cURL. Es decir, programas una petición cURL en tu propio servidor hacia la API de `geovictoria` y luego desde Ajax llamas a ese archivo `.php` que estaría en tu servidor y que te devolvería los datos en forma de JSON o lo que sea.

Comment: Si quieres una solución sencilla y rápida podrías hacer 2 cosas: Instalar una extensión ya sea en chrome o edge (No uso más navegadores) escribes CORS en la búsqueda e instalas una y como segunda opción puedes entrar a este link [Cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo) y le das al botón **request temporary access to the demo server** y en tu url lo agregas así: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemohttps://customerapi-sandbox.geovictoria.com/api/v1/Login` ojo como dice allí es solo con fines de desarrollo ya si quieres algo mejor podrías hacer lo que dijo Yussef